# How to update freeze authority in solana nft

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex

I have a SOLANA NFT that I mint, can I update 'freezeAuthority' using '@solana/spl-token' or '@metaplex-foundation'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Freeze Authority is transfered to the Master Edition Account PDA, so no one can change it. The good part is that spl-token program has the `Approve` instruction that allows you to become the `FreezeDelegatedAccount` and then you will be able to Freeze the NFT using the [`FreezeDelegatedAccount` instruction](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/instructions#freeze-the-token-account-as-a-delegate).